# ERPNext | RestAPI | Cancel Endpoint

Tags: rest, crud, erpnext

How can I cancel someone's attendance on ERPNext using RestAPI? I checked the documentation on ERPNext but it did not have anything on this. I also tried updating the attendance using the CRUD operations but the response gave status code = 500 I tried deleting the record and it gave the error that I have to cancel the record first then I can delete it. I know I can cancel it using the UI but I want to do this using the RestAPI.

Comment: if you can do it through browser then use web browser dev tools to see which api being used

Comment: @sahasrara62  so there do i need to use the 'request URL' inside Header section of Network under Developer tools as my API endpoint?

Comment: yes u need to check there

Comment: @sahasrara62 it is giving Internal Server Error (500) when i tried the Request URL as my endpoint

Comment: @sahasrara62 do you have any other method to do this. It was giving Internal Server Error because the it was using Cookie-based authentication. and when i put everything in my header by copying from the Inspection window it is giving FORBIDDEN error.

Comment: i dont know much on this part but if this way you can debug and tell which api is being used. if you also have code access then you can check it there easilsy